# excel: error 1004. Reference isn't valid no idea why

Tags: excel

I apparently have an issue with the tird row of this code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Datos!R1C1:R1048576C52", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "'Temporal'!R1C1", TableName:="PivotHatchList", DefaultVersion:=6
```

what can it be?

Comment: please describe for others wha your maro is supposed to do and give a bit of context

Comment: i believe that `"Datos!R1C1:R1048576C52"` should be a range object: `Worksheets("Datos").Range("A1:AZ1048576")` but pivot tables need to not have blanks in the range and I doubt you have 52 full columns of data.